# Which manga chapter of Natsume Yuujinchou has a mask youkai that possesses people?

Tags: natsumes-book-of-friends

Which chapter was the chapter where Natsume pretends to be Matoba's blind shiki so that he can feel people's faces and determine whether they are being possessed by a youkai?
From my memory, the youkai was a mask that attached itself to people or something...

Answer (score 2):

Manga chapter 53-54. Anime season 5 (Natsume Yuujinchou Go) episode 4.